# using method from enum class, when the enum is obtained during runtime

Tags: java, enums

I have a class

```
public class AT{
    public Map getMap(){
        Map<String,Class> map = new HashMap<>(); 
        map.put("name",AT.A.class); 
        map.put("name",AT.B.class);
        return map;
    }

    public enum A {;
        a,b,c,d;
        public static String getTableName() {
            return "table_nameA" ;
        }
    }
    public enum B {;
        e,f,g,h;
        public static String getTableName() {
            return "table_nameB" ;
        }
    }
}
```

I will get a string `s` from user from which can be use to get enum class `A` from the `map`.

Main class ->

```
AT at = new AT();
Map<String,Class > map = new HashMap<>(at.getMap());
System.out.println(map.get(s).getEnumConstants()[0]);  //will give a;
```

But I am not able to access the function `getTableName`

```
System.out.println( map.get(s).getTableName() ); //want to use this but doesn't work.
```

Comment: What do you think `Class` is? Why do you think so?

Comment: Your `AT` class (as presented) won't compile.

Comment: A is an enum class, right ?

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah I made a error there, now it is done correct. Can you tell me how to made that method work.

Comment: Nope. Still won't compile. Why don't you just try to?

Comment: @PM77-1 made the changes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't get u.

Answer (score 0):

Have each enum implement an interface.

This compiles:

```
import java.util.*;
interface TableName {
    String get();
}
class AT {
    public Map<String,Class> getMap() {
        Map<String,Class> map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name",AT.A.class);
        map.put("name",AT.B.class);
        return map;
    }
    public enum A implements TableName {
        a,b,c,d;
        public String get() {
            return "table_nameA";
        }
    }
    public enum B implements TableName {
        e,f,g,h;
        public String get() {
            return "table_nameB";
        }
    }
}
```